# What dodgy scams are there to get to the top of Google searches?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

I was speaking to a relative and they mentioned that the designer/developer who produced their site had a way of getting them to the first page of google, I did advise him that this could be potentially dodgy and if he's not using legit SEO techniques then you could get thrown out.

So what dodgy packages are there at the moment that he could be using, because from the look of the site and the number of orders it's taking, I really can't see how it could've organically risen to the top.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may not be able to see it because you're not looking in the right place. For example, there's no way to find all of the incoming links to their site.

Comment: You probably should just get in touch with his web developer to find out if you really want to know. Obviously don't come at him with, "So, what crappy fake SEO tricks are you pulling with my relatives site?". But you could get in touch and pick his brain with something like, "I hear you have some special SEO techniques you are using to help my relatives site. Can you tell me more about your strategies?"

Comment: Well, this is why I'm asking here, because he has vanished off the face of the earth, and now that they may have the site re-written I'm worried they will drop off the first page.  I have access to Google Webmaster and there are no incoming links to the site and the top keywords have nothing to do with what they are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using a 'Link farm' of some sort. Paying to have other websites link to their website.

"Dodgy scams" as you call them are called "Black Hat SEO Techniques" you can search for examples on google such as:

http://www.seoptimise.com/blog/2010/01/30-black-hat-seo-techniques-you-can-use-ethically.html